# Retrieve background-image URL from element

Tags: jquery

I have this code generated by a js file. I want to grab the value of backgroun-image. I want to take the url in order to change it later on a click. How can i do that via jQuery?

```
<div class="slider_image" id="content_20" style="width: 450px; height: 137px; top: 0px; left: 0px;  position: inherit; background-image: url(http://example.com/images/5656dd4934050.png);"></div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css. Also note that I would suggest you instead put all of these style rules in a stylesheet and switch classes on click, instead of hacking around CSS properties on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Triggering click event on some element.
$("#someid").click(function(){

var bg = $('#content_20').css('background-image'); // Fetch Background image

$('#content_20').css('background-image','url(img/1.jpg)'); // Setting new background image.

});
```

Comment: if i had this class -> class="slider_image content image"

Answer (score 0):

try this [(jQuery `css()` documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$(".slider_image").css('background-image')
```

Answer (score 0):

$( "div" ).click(function() {
  var image= $( this ).css( "background-image" );

try this if you don't have option

But my preference will be changing the css class on click. its good practice and also performance improves